# How does Haskell compile the large numbers?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I would just like to know how it works at compilation time. GHC, for its interpreter, uses the GMP library to generate and manipulate very large numbers, but an executable compiled by GHC does not have a third-party GMP library to carry. So how does the compiler keep the same accuracy? Does the executable have its own implementations of large number manipulations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the program:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- readLn :: IO Integer
  print $ x + 1
```

and compile it on a Linux machine with the `-v` flag:

```
$ ghc -v AddOne.hs
```

then you'll find near the end of the verbose output the `gcc` command that's used to link the executable together:

```
*** Linker:
gcc -fno-stack-protector -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE '-fuse-ld=gold' ...
```

It's a really long line, but if you search through it, you should find (probably near the end) a set of external libraries being linked in:

```
...  -lHSrts -lCffi -lgmp -lm -lrt -ldl -lpthread
```

That `-lgmp` there is linking in the GMP library.

You can also use the `ldd` command to show that there's a dependency on the system GMP library in the executable:

```
$ ldd AddOne
...
        libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fc0da1fa000)
...
```

At least, this is the case on my system with a recent version of GHC running under Stack.  If you find that on your system there is no GMP dependency, it's probably just because things have been configured to statically link the required GMP code into the executable instead of dynamically linking at runtime.  (For example, I think on Windows, GMP code is statically linked by default.)

To make things slightly more complicated, it is possible to use an [integer library other than GMP](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/replacing-gmp-notes), though this needs to be done at the time GHC itself is compiled.  One alternative mentioned in that link is the `integer-simple` library, which is a Haskell implementation of large integer operations that's part of the GHC source tree.  So, in that particular case, the executable would be using its own implementation of large number manipulations.  I don't think you're likely to find a standard, pre-compiled GHC that uses something other than GMP, though.

Answer (score 0):

GHC-compiled executables implement `Integer` using GMP.

> an executable compiled by GHC does not have a third-party GMP library to carry

If by that you mean that GHC-compiled executables don't link against GMP, you're mistaken. They do.